# Exlpode xml and turn into array

Tags: php, xml, database, curl

I want to know how to explode or split xml and turn into array and then insert it to database. Because i have an api that need to hit every day and it return xml.

here's my xml sample:

```
<ArrayOfUnitPrice>
 <UnitPrice>
  <PriceAmount>1579.7080</PriceAmount>
  <PriceDate>2016-09-02</PriceDate>
  <PriceType>XWZ</PriceType>
 </UnitPrice>
 <UnitPrice>
  <PriceAmount>1028.4137</PriceAmount>
  <PriceDate>2016-09-02</PriceDate>
  <PriceType>ABC</PriceType>
 </UnitPrice>
 ...
</ArrayOfUnitPrice>
```

I'm using this code to extract the xml response:

```
$ch = curl_init("111.222.333.444:8080/code.asmx/Price");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);

//my code here

curl_close($ch);
```

**SOLVED**
I already done solve my code by using this code below guys.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

for ($i=0; $i < count($xml) ; $i++) {
  $arr[] = array (
  'PriceAmount' => $xml->UnitPrice[$i]->PriceAmount,
  'PriceDate' => $xml->UnitPrice[$i]->PriceDate,
  'PriceType' => $xml->UnitPrice[$i]->PriceType
  );
}
$data = json_decode(json_encode($arr), true);
$servername   = "localhost";
$username     = "root";
$password     = "";
$dbname       = "dailywork";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(is_array($data)){
    $check = "SELECT * FROM table_unit";
    if($conn->query($check)->num_rows > 0){
      // my stuff to here :-D
    }else{
      /*Insert data to DB*/
      $sql = "INSERT INTO table_unit (PriceAmount, PriceDate, PriceType) values ";
      $valuesArr = array();
      foreach($data as $row){
          $PriceAmount  = $row[PriceAmount][0];
          $PriceDate    = $row[PriceDate][0];
          $PriceType    = $row[PriceType][0];
          $valuesArr[]  = "('$PriceAmount', '$PriceDate', '$PriceType')";
      }
      $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
      /*End Insert data to DB*/
    }
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Are you using a SOAP API?

Comment: @GrzegorzB.yes,thats right

Answer (score 1):

This function will give you an array of your xml

```
function xml2php($xmlcontent) 
{
  $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
  xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $xmlcontent, $arr_vals);
  xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
  return $arr_vals;
}
```

pass your $result like this and check it

```
xml2php($result);
```

let me know if it helps you

Comment: sorry dude, i wasn't able to understand your code so i use other code to solve it. but really appreciate your help. thanks @rahul